# Changing <a-mixin> material texture with a javascript ID on a button press

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

So I have the following code:

```js
 function pictureChange()
  {
   document.getElementById("theImage").src="img02.png";
  }
```

```html
<a-mixin id="voxel"
         geometry="primitive: box; height: 0.6; width: 0.6; depth: 0.6"
         material="id: theImage; src: Box.jpg; color: #696969; roughness: 1; metalness: 0"     
         snap="offset: 0.4 0.4 0.4; snap: 0.6 0.6 0.6"
      ></a-mixin>
```

And I wanted to use the ID "theImage" to change the image url to somthing else, but CSS3 in Aframe doesn't work the same so I can't get it to run properly. If anybody has any ideas that might help me, it would be very appreciated. Thanks.

PS: to clarify, I want some way to change the url by the press of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id refers to an entity or asset, not a material. Try setting the image on the mixin:

```
  var mixinEl = document.getElementById('voxel');
  mixinEl.setAttribute('material','src: #super');
```

Example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/swamp-sparrow?path=index.html:1:0

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Updated glitch to add a button. If you mark answer as correct it will be appreciated.

Comment: There you go. Thank you so much. It worked for what I needed. One more question though, where it has the event listener, how would you make it change the texture by pressing the space bar, instead of clicking? It's not important, just something I would like to learn to do.